# Loading footer in error pages based on routing group

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade, laravel-routing

I have default `errors/404.blade.php` and I have a route group say `admin` (I may have more route groups).

Now, of course, I have separate header and footer templates for the default routes and  each route groups.

```
.
.     
|-- resources
    |-- views
      |-- ..                   (other views)
      |-- errors
          |-- 404.blade.php
          |-- 503.blade.php
      |-- partials
          |-- ..
          |-- header.blade.php
          |-- footer.blade.php
      |-- pages
          |-- ..
          |-- admin
              |-- ..
              |-- partials
                  |-- header.blade.php
                  |-- footer.blade.php
```

Say I'm in my `site.com/admin/` route and I get a 404 `error` by visiting a page like so,
`site.com/admin/some-non-existent-page`

By default my `errors/404.blade.php` is hardcoded to use the `/views/partials/footer.blade.php`

How can I make it `dynamic`, so that it displays the footer from the route group I'm currently in or the default one if I'm on one of the main pages?

Answer (score 0):

Use **Request::segment()**

for example take this url...
stackoverflow.com/questions/34605065/loading-footer-in-error-pages-based-on-routing-group

Request::segment(2)= questions

Request::segment(3)= 34605065

use if else condition with **Request::segment()**..i think this will solve your problem.